# how to count over everything in r studio

Tags: rstudio

I organizaed my data so that I get an output that gives me counts by modality. for example,

```
     Resident Location      Year                    Modality  PGY ModalityCount
```

47  john smith      SMH 2009-2010                          CT PGY2            12
48  john smith      SMH 2009-2010                         MRI PGY2             4

However, I would like to make the counts overall counts of how many counts of scans they did overall.
How would i do this?

Thanks